# AMCL: No laser scan received

Tags: navigation, ros-kinetic, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone!

After generating a map with a SLAM, I wanted to localize my robot in this map. For that purpose I want to use AMCL package. But I keep getting the same error:

```
[ WARN] [1560764535.601073091, 398.853000000]: No laser scan received (and thus no pose updates have been published) for 398.853000 seconds.  Verify that data is being published on the /amazon_warehouse_robot/laser/scan topic.

[ WARN] [1560764535.614184813, 398.865000000]: MessageFilter [target=odom ]: Dropped 100.00% of messages so far. Please turn the [ros.amcl.message_notifier] rosconsole logger to DEBUG for more information.
```

I use the ROS Kinetic, Ubuntu 16.04, Gazebo

I do the following:

```
roslaunch amazon_navigation amazonrobot_1_warehouse.launch

rosrun map_server map_server map.yaml

rosrun amcl amcl scan:=amazon_warehouse_robot/laser/scan _odom_frame:=amazon_warehouse_robot/odom
```

and

```
rostopic echo /amazon_warehouse_robot/laser/scan
```

gives:

```
header: 
  seq: 2
  stamp: 
    secs: 1
    nsecs: 101000000
  frame_id: "amazon_warehouse_robot/hokuyo_link"
angle_min: -1.57000005245
angle_max: 1.57000005245
angle_increment: 0.0175419002771
time_increment: 0.0
scan_time: 0.0
range_min: 0.0799999982119
range_max: 10.0
ranges: [inf, inf, 6.664645671844482, 4.669021129608154, 3.3098554611206055, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, 5.578123569488525, ....]
intensities: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...]
```

---

```
rostopic echo /amazon_warehouse_robot/odom

header: 
  seq: 1785
  stamp: 
    secs: 178
    nsecs: 601000000
  frame_id: "amazon_warehouse_robot/odom"
child_frame_id: "amazon_warehouse_robot/base"
pose: 
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: 0.000142417215952
      y: 0.00111615755185
      z: 0.050002391371
    orientation: 
      x: -1.3005763226e-07
      y: -2.34663847428e-07
      z: 4.42450664072e-05
      w: 0.999999999021
  covariance: [1e-05, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...]
twist: 
  twist: 
    linear: 
      x: 0.000189513575366
      y: 0.000217444901386
      z: 0.0
    angular: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 2.97531367781e-06
  covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0,...]


rostopic list

/amazon_warehouse_robot/cmd_vel
/amazon_warehouse_robot/joint_cmd
/amazon_warehouse_robot/joint_states
/amazon_warehouse_robot/laser/scan
/amazon_warehouse_robot/odom
/amcl/parameter_descriptions
/amcl/parameter_updates
/amcl_pose
/clock
/gazebo/link_states
/gazebo/model_states
/gazebo/parameter_descriptions
/gazebo/parameter_updates
/gazebo/set_link_state
/gazebo/set_model_state
/gazebo_gui/parameter_descriptions
/gazebo_gui/parameter_updates
/initialpose
/map
/map_metadata
/particlecloud
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/tf
/tf_static
```

tf tree looks like this:

```
amazon_warehouse_robot/odom  
                   ⇩ 
amazon_warehouse_robot/base
                   ⇩                                                                                             
amazon_warehouse_robot/hokuyo_link
```

I also did a transform:

```
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="map_to_odom" 
    args="0 0 0.1 0 0 0 1.0 /map /amazon_warehouse_robot/odom 100" />
```

but it didn't had any effect. As I am aware, AMCL should publish its own transform

I have gone through all similar answers, but still nothing changed. One of them was suggesting that if you have non integer value "inf" for me, that may be the cause of the problem, but I have added a filter to laserscan and result was the same.

Any help is appreciated!! I don't know what to do now

```
$ roswtf
the rosdep view is empty: call 'sudo rosdep init' and 'rosdep update'
No package or stack in context
================================================================================
Static checks summary:

Found 1 error(s).

ERROR ROS Dep database not updated: Please update rosdep database with 'rosdep update'.
================================================================================
Beginning tests of your ROS graph. These may take awhile...
analyzing graph...
... done analyzing graph
running graph rules...
... done running graph rules

Online checks summary:

Found 1 warning(s).
Warnings are things that may be just fine, but are sometimes at fault

WARNING The following node subscriptions are unconnected:
 * /amcl:
   * /tf_static
   * /initialpose
 * /gazebo:
   * /gazebo/set_link_state
   * /gazebo/set_model_state
   * /amazon_warehouse_robot/joint_cmd
   * /amazon_warehouse_robot/cmd_vel


$ rostopic info /amazon_warehouse_robot/laser/scan
Type: sensor_msgs/LaserScan

Publishers: 
 * /gazebo (http://shyngys-HP-ENVY-15-Notebook-PC:41995/)

Subscribers: 
 * /amcl (http://shyngys-HP-ENVY-15-Notebook-PC:38675/)

$ rostopic info /amazon_warehouse_robot/odom
Type: nav_msgs/Odometry

Publishers: 
 * /gazebo (http://shyngys-HP-ENVY-15-Notebook-PC:41995/)

Subscribers: None
```

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/325980/amcl:-no-laser-scan-received/) by [kurshakuz](https://answers.ros.org/users/42874/kurshakuz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2019-06-17

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kurshakuz](https://answers.ros.org/users/42874/kurshakuz/) on 2019-06-17**:
My launch file is following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<launch>
  <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
    <arg name="world_name" value="amazonrobot_1_warehouse.world"/> 
    <arg name="paused" value="false"/>
    <arg name="use_sim_time" value="true"/>
    <arg name="gui" value="true"/>
    <arg name="headless" value="false"/>
    <arg name="debug" value="false"/>
    <arg name="verbose" default="true"/>
  </include>

 <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_to_laser" 
    args="0.139000 0.000000 0.15 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 /amazon_warehouse_robot/base /amazon_warehouse_robot/hokuyo_link 20" />

<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_to_chassis" 
    args="0 0 0.1 0 0 0 1.0  /amazon_warehouse_robot/base /amazon_warehouse_robot/amazon_warehouse_robot::chassis 100" />

</launch>
```

**Comment by [kosmastsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/36854/kosmastsk/) on 2019-06-17**:
What is the frame_id of the map that you are loading? Try adding this as a parameter in the map_server node and set it to "/map" and see if anything changes

**Comment by [ChuiV](https://answers.ros.org/users/30013/chuiv/) on 2019-06-17**:
Just to be sure, try changing
`rosrun amcl amcl scan:=amazon_warehouse_robot/laser/scan _odom_frame:=amazon_warehouse_robot/odom`
to
`rosrun amcl amcl scan:=/amazon_warehouse_robot/laser/scan _odom_frame:=/amazon_warehouse_robot/odom`

namespacing has gotten me a couple times.

**Comment by [kurshakuz](https://answers.ros.org/users/42874/kurshakuz/) on 2019-06-18**:
Hi @kosmastsk! I have added the following:

```
<node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(find amazon_navigation)/maps/map.yaml">
    <param name="frame_id" value="/map"/>
  </node>
```

and get the following warning:

```
Frame_id of map received:'/map' doesn't match global_frame_id:'map'. This could cause issues with reading published topics
```

But if I change the value to map (without a /) warning disappears, but I keep getting the same error as in the question

**Comment by [kurshakuz](https://answers.ros.org/users/42874/kurshakuz/) on 2019-06-18**:
@ChuiV the problem is still there :(

**Comment by [damjan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2702/damjan/) on 2019-06-18**:
Could you post the output of `rosnode info /amcl`, `rostopic info /amazon_warehouse_robot/laser/scan` and `rostopic info /amazon_warehouse_robot/odom`? Also, try running `roswtf` and post your rqt_graph.

**Comment by [kurshakuz](https://answers.ros.org/users/42874/kurshakuz/) on 2019-06-22**:
@damjan

```
rosnode info /amcl
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Node [/amcl]
Publications: 
 * /amcl/parameter_descriptions [dynamic_reconfigure/ConfigDescription]
 * /amcl/parameter_updates [dynamic_reconfigure/Config]
 * /amcl_pose [geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped]
 * /particlecloud [geometry_msgs/PoseArray]
 * /rosout [rosgraph_msgs/Log]
 * /tf [tf2_msgs/TFMessage]

Subscriptions: 
 * /amazon_warehouse_robot/laser/scan [sensor_msgs/LaserScan]
 * /clock [rosgraph_msgs/Clock]
 * /initialpose [unknown type]
 * /tf [tf2_msgs/TFMessage]
 * /tf_static [unknown type]

Services: 
 * /amcl/get_loggers
 * /amcl/set_logger_level
 * /amcl/set_parameters
 * /global_localization
 * /request_nomotion_update
 * /set_map
```

**Comment by [kurshakuz](https://answers.ros.org/users/42874/kurshakuz/) on 2019-06-22**:
@damjan I also have added more info to the question. Please have a look, thanks for help :)

**Comment by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) on 2019-06-22**:
A note that may or may not help.
My laser scan header does not have " "  around the frame id:

```
header: 
  seq: 1194
  stamp: 
    secs: 1561227281
    nsecs: 427794935
  frame_id: laser
angle_min: 0.0
```

In your post the frame id is in quotations:

```
header: 
  seq: 2 
  stamp: 
    secs: 1 
    nsecs: 101000000 
  frame_id: "amazon_warehouse_robot/hokuyo_link" 
angle_min: -1.57000005245
```

I am using JADE and that may be the difference, but alos possible AMCL doesn't find it because frame id shows it incorrectly. IDK. Good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your `_odom_frame` parameter should actually be `_odom_frame_id` and you are missing the `_base_frame_id` parameter, i.e., i think that your `rosrun` command should look like this:

```
rosrun amcl amcl scan:=amazon_warehouse_robot/laser/scan _odom_frame_id:=amazon_warehouse_robot/odom _base_frame_id:=amazon_warehouse_robot/base
```

Please re-check the frame names. You can check that the AMCL parameters have been set correctly with `rosparam get /amcl/odom_frame_id` and `rosparam get /amcl/base_frame_id`.

---

Originally posted by [damjan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2702/damjan/) with karma: 446 on 2019-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kurshakuz](https://answers.ros.org/users/42874/kurshakuz/) on 2019-06-24**:
Thank you very much! That worked

**Comment by [damjan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2702/damjan/) on 2019-06-24**:
Glad to have helped! :) That LaserScan timeout error is actually quite misleading.

**Comment by [frans](https://answers.ros.org/users/86704/frans/) on 2021-10-08**:
hi i have the same issue too, can you help me pls.. im using rplidar a1m8, and in my case the warning is: " No laser scan received (and thus no pose updates have been published) for 1633685695.210126 seconds.  Verify that data is being published on the /scan topic". im stuck....